# What are the most recognized Italian language certifications available for foreign language speakers?

Tags: resources

I have a firm plan to attempt official Italian language exams. After searching on the internet I have come across about a few of them like CELI, CILS, and PLIDA. Can anyone suggest me which ones are most recognized and ideal and what should be the learning route for a foreign student whose native language is not Italian.

Please guide and provide authentic information. Grazie Mille :)

Comment: I think they are all equally recognized, as least in my country is that way, as you can see from [this document](http://xtec.gencat.cat/web/.content/alfresco/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/0031/31edd239-3bb4-4118-97f9-2bd977cbe00e/equil-italia.pdf). Anyway, in my country it's quite advisable to take the exams of the Official School of Languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be any exam compliant with the CEFR.
http://www.coe.int/t/dg4/linguistic/Cadre1_en.asp

Answer (score 4):

To add to WGroleau's answer, according to the University of Manchester, "The PLIDA (Progetto Lingua Italiana Dante Alighieri) certificate is an official Diploma issued by the Società Dante Alighieri under an agreement with the Italian Ministry of Foreign Affairs. It is recognised by the Italian Ministry of Labour and Social Policies and by the Italian Ministry of University and Research as a qualification for the proficiency in the Italian language for foreigners." [(More here)](http://www.alc.manchester.ac.uk/modern-languages/study/languages/italian-studies/plida-certificate/)

[PLIDA](http://plida.it/) follows the parameters set out by CEFR.

As an aside, I am currently studying for the Plida A2 and am thoroughly enjoying it.

Comment: Plida sounds interesting. Thank you for the tip. I've recently picked up my Italian studies after maby years and was wondering what to aim for.. this could be an interesting and challenging goal

Answer (score 2):

I live in Thessaloniki, Greece, and I studied Italian language in many schools in order to obtain my first degree. My last school was Galileo Galilei (you can find it in  Facebook), a well organised school with good teachers. My sincere opinion is to be prepared for CILS (A2) or CILS (B1) or, if you feel in good level, for CILS (B2) because CILS is from the University of Siena, it is easier than CELI, PLIDA or DIPLOMA  (held by the Italian Institute). Last year I took exams for CILS (B2) and I took it with a good grade. As they told us CELI is quite complicated with negative grade if you make mistakes, PLIDA has many literature points to know and finally Diploma has very difficult orale in order to take the exams again and again (until 3 times you have the right to participate). Now I  continue to study the Italian language because I love it very much in private lessons and I am very pleased.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation as Muhammad some months ago, so I asked several people and they advised me to do the CILS because, according to them, it's the most widely recognised one, especially if you consider studying/working at an Italian university at some point in the future.

I trust the people that told me this (as a matter of fact, I did what they recommended), but they might be wrong, so take my advice carefully!

In addition, the availability of the exams in your area is obviously a plus. If you have CILS exams in your city (as I do), it'll be way easier to prepare yourself and taking the exam will be much more convenient. In my case, I'd have to travel 500 km or more to do the other ones!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!